# using geometric series rules when solving Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

when looking at Laurent Series expansions, I sometimes see something like:
$$
\frac{1}{\sin z}=
\frac{1}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)}=\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+\ldots\right)
$$

can anyone explain why $ \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)} $
is equal to $ (1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+\ldots) $ ?

and what should I do in the general case of $ \frac{1}{\text{alternating-series}} $?
I often see that it is evaluated to a positive series. why is that?

Comment: For $x\sim0$ $$(1+x)^{-1}\sim 1-x+\dots$$

Comment: Dario, can you please elaborate? In my example there are two infinite series, one of them alternating. I can't seem to figure out the connection to your answer

Comment: Instead of $x$ you have $-\frac{z^2}{6}+\dots$ that is something small... If you replace $x$ with the first terms of your expansion (and maybe considering some higher order term of $(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots$) you should obtain what you have written (You have to consider terms up to the forth order).

Comment: I dont think it is equal - $O(z^4)$ term is wrong -- see answer for general approach. The series for sin is not geometric.

Answer (score 1):

Your expansion is wrong: you can check with Mathematica that
$$
\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{7z^4}{360}+o(z^4)\right)
$$
As I wrote in the comments  you can use the two expansions:
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^5)$$
and
$$(1+y)^{-1}=1-y+y^2+o(y^2)\ .$$
Now you have
$$\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{z}\left[1+\left(-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+o(z^4)\right)\right]^{-1}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{z}\left[1-\left(-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+o(z^4)\right)+\left(-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+o(z^4)\right)^2+o(z^4)\right]=$$
$$=\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+\frac{z^4}{36}+o(z^4)\right)\ ,$$
where in the last step I absorbed all term of order higher than 4 in $o(z^4)$. This is exactly the expansion I wrote at the beginning and the same you obtain with Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha.